# pdf reader that supports tabs

Tags: pdf, tabs

I want a pdf that is sort of browser-like , I mean that you can open many pdfs and one session and navigate between them in tabs,

foxit reader does that on windows, I don't know about foxit reader on linux because I Couldn't install it, I get the same problem as this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67432/how-do-i-install-foxit-reader-1-1)

so would someone suggest a nice "isntallable" pdf reader that supports tabs, or just tell us a way to make foxit reader work here

Comment: you can read pdf from mozilla too...checkout http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Opening%20PDF%20files%20within%20Firefox

Comment: Please see my answer to [How do I install Foxit Reader 1.1?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67432/how-do-i-install-foxit-reader-1-1/109541#109541)

Comment: you can vote - and contribute - here https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=155515 for Okular

Answer (score 21):

[qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview) supports tabs and seems very good. I have it as the default pdf reader and so far found no problem.

Install it as follows,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:b-eltzner/qpdfview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qpdfview
```

Comment: With Ubuntu 18 LTS, just "sudo apt-get install qpdfview" is enough. No need to add the repo anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Firefox 19+ now does native PDF display, and of course has tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The Adobe Reader from the [acroread](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AcrobatHowTo) package does have tabs, but it is not the most lightweight pdf-reader of them all, if you know what I mean.

Comment: I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Mendeley Desktop is quite lightweight for a tabbed pdf viewer, imo. plus it has tons of other features, too

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Nufail, qpdfview is the best option for the description you gave.

However, one great (but which has a lot of extra functionality than what you need) solution I came across is [Master PDF](https://code-industry.net/masterpdfeditor/). It is designed to edit the pdf, but has great solutions for viewing and marking the document as well.

Hope this helps other users who arrive at this page.