# PDF viewer that lists open documents

Tags: pdf, menu

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a document viewer that has a *menu* of some kind that shows all my open documents.  I typically have anywhere between 5 and 20 PDFs open when I'm doing research, and using Super-W or clicking the dock icon to "explode" all the windows is totally useless.  On my Mac, most applications have a "Window" menu that shows all open documents in a nice list, like this: [image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you mean in Unity, you can right clic in the icon to show all open windows.

Comment: Huh, indeed you can.  Also, I just finally found [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38505/how-can-i-see-a-list-of-all-open-windows-in-a-panel-in-unity) answer that has several other options.  Thanks @xangua!

Comment: @icurays1 If that's the case, close as a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Using the window manager, as recommended by @xangua, is always a good option. But if you are looking for a way to specifically keep your PDF documents grouped together and easily switch between them you could try out one of the tabbed PDF apps recommended in [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89425/pdf-reader-that-supports-tabs/165427).

My personal favorite would be [qpdfview](https://launchpad.net/qpdfview), a highly customizable and lighting-fast PDF viewer with very active development. Here's a quick screenshot of a multi-tab session:

[image]

qpdfview also offers an overview of all open tabs via the *Tabs* menu.