# Why Flush torrent client would not start?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, lubuntu, torrent-client

**Flush** is a torrent client similar to Deluge or Qbittorrent, is the lightest, and I have used it along Qbittorrent without any problem for some time.

But after reinstalling the OS I used only Qbittorent for a while; now when I want to try Flush again I have a problem: after I install it, execute it, and see some action of the processor (i see that light flashing a few secs like when a program starts), but then nothing happens.

At first view, this looks similar to [a problem reported in connection with FoxitReader](https://askubuntu.com/q/67432/47206), that I also encountered and [solved according to the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/109541/47206). It would have been similar, except that in the case of FoxitReader the program was absent in usr/bin, and putting it there manually after extracting it from deb solved the problem. In the case of Flush, **it is already in usr/bin**. I see it in Synaptic, in launcher, in menu, in `run`(alt-f2) and usr/bin: nothing works.

(In the case of FoxitReader,  the program appeared in menu, launcher, and synaptic, but **not** in run and **not** in usr/bin.)

I have installed Flush from Synaptic (currently 0.9.12) and have also tried the deb version 0.9.10 with identical results.

(I'm in Lubuntu 12.04).

(The same happens when I try Frostwire.)

**Edit after comment**: after running `flush` in Terminal I get:

```
~$ flush
(flush:3711): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.3/./glib/goption.c:2179: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (8) on option of arg-type 0 in entry main:version

(flush:3711): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.3/./glib/goption.c:2179: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (16) on option of arg-type 4 in entry main:config

(flush:3711): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.3/./glib/goption.c:2179: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg    or filename flags (8) on option of arg-type 0 in entry main:only-pass

flush: symbol lookup error: flush: undefined symbol: _ZN10libtorrent7sessionC1ERKNS_11fingerprintEii
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be a compiling/linking bug with flush: that undefined symbol is provided by `libtorrent-rasterbar6`, which seems to be installed.

So you can try to reinstall `libtorrent-rasterbar6` and see if you get anything different:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libtorrent-rasterbar6
```

Also, there is a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~konishchevdmitry/+archive/flush) that seems to be maintained by the creator of Flush, and so it should be safe for you to try it:

```
sudo apt-get remove flush libtorrent-rasterbar6
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:konishchevdmitry/flush 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install flush
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i hope this will help the others, i have upgraded to 12.10 and flush started working.